# Is Netty4 ChannelHandlerContext.write thread safe

Tags: multithreading, netty

Looking into the code, seems it isn't thread safe. If not , how can I write data in a thread-safe way?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is thread-safe. Same is true for all ChannelHandlerContext, Channel and ChannelPipeline operations.

Comment: Thanks. Which line of code guarantee the thread-safty? Could you please give a few words to describe it?

Comment: Check DefaultChannelHandlerContext and look into how it use inEventLoop()